# Reading un-even JSON with Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, data-structures, iteration

I have a program that's taking a LARGE JSON file and reading through the structure, grabbing everything where the key matches something, then storing a number of items form that structure into the database. The problem is that sometimes the structure is off when there is only one item... so as follows:

```
                "stats": {
                    "first": [
                        {
                            "name": "Name1",
                            "context": "open",
                            "number": "139"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Name2",
                            "context": "opener",
                            "number": "135"
                        }
                    ],
                    "second": {
                        "name": "Name1",
                        "context": "opener",
                        "amount": "1.5",
                        "number": "-125"
                    },
                    "third": [
                        {
                            "name": "Name1",
                            "context": "open",
                            "amount": "8.5",
                            "number": "-110"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Name2",
                            "context": "open",
                            "amount": "9.0",
                            "number": "-120"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
```

So, you'll notice that second only has one entry, so it's structured differently... I've tried more conditionals than I can think of... how do I check if it's a single entry and move forward?  This is probably REALLY simple, I'm just at a loss and not the best at Python data structures (admittedly).

What I'm doing after is grabbign like third[0]['name'] and putting it into a database... so I get an index error when I try on that second node. Also - in some nodes, second WILL have more than one... in others it won't... totally depends on the record.

Comment: You can handle the `IndexError` and assume that means you've got a dictionary not a list: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: You should also find the person who generated the file and [slap them with a trout](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IhJQp-q1Y1s).

Comment: Considering we're paying for teh feed, I'm bringing it up.

Answer (score 3):

I would first parse it to a JSON, and then update the dictionary you describe that has keys like `"first"`, `"second"`, etc. as follows:

```
def repair_dict(d):
    for k in list(d):
        v = d[k]
        if not isinstance(v,list):
            d[k] = [v]
```

It thus repairs the data like:

```
>>> d = json.loads(data)
>>> d
{'stats': {'third': [{'context': 'open', 'name': 'Name1', 'number': '-110', 'amount': '8.5'}, {'context': 'open', 'name': 'Name2', 'number': '-120', 'amount': '9.0'}], 'second': {'context': 'opener', 'name': 'Name1', 'number': '-125', 'amount': '1.5'}, 'first': [{'context': 'open', 'name': 'Name1', 'number': '139'}, {'context': 'opener', 'name': 'Name2', 'number': '135'}]}}
>>> repair_dict(d['stats'])
>>> d
{'stats': {'third': [{'context': 'open', 'name': 'Name1', 'number': '-110', 'amount': '8.5'}, {'context': 'open', 'name': 'Name2', 'number': '-120', 'amount': '9.0'}], 'second': [{'context': 'opener', 'name': 'Name1', 'number': '-125', 'amount': '1.5'}], 'first': [{'context': 'open', 'name': 'Name1', 'number': '139'}, {'context': 'opener', 'name': 'Name2', 'number': '135'}]}}
```

Or when pretty printing:

```
>>> pprint.pprint(d)
{'stats': {'first': [{'context': 'open', 'name': 'Name1', 'number': '139'},
                     {'context': 'opener', 'name': 'Name2', 'number': '135'}],
           'second': [{'amount': '1.5',
                       'context': 'opener',
                       'name': 'Name1',
                       'number': '-125'}],
           'third': [{'amount': '8.5',
                      'context': 'open',
                      'name': 'Name1',
                      'number': '-110'},
                     {'amount': '9.0',
                      'context': 'open',
                      'name': 'Name2',
                      'number': '-120'}]}}
```

Comment: Hmmmm to be more specific, I AM loading the data using json.loads:

`h = requests.get(OPENER_URL)`
    `new_data = json.loads(h.text)`

Comment: @Jenni: that's not the point of the answer. You then can call `repair_dict` on the parts of the resulting dictionary that need to be repaired. Check the second code fragment to see how the dictionary changes.

Comment: OH! Thank you - I'm swimming over here... and every resulting call is getting worse lol.  I'm going to try this one and see if I can make that work!